# Why are global fields defined how they are?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, intuition, class-field-theory

The way a global field has always been described to me is a field that is either a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, or  a field of rational functions on a projective curve over a field of characteristic $p$ (i.e., finite extensions of $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$).

This definition never made much sense to me. Sure, we use it all the time and can come up with some pretty cool results using it, but *intuitively* it never made sense why those two classes of fields are related. On a high level, what is the connection between these two types of fields?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_field#Analogies_between_the_two_classes_of_fields

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1367/global-fields-what-exactly-is-the-analogy-between-number-fields-and-function-fi).